# add application listener by code

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, app-config

i want convert every thing to C# code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="NewListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing" >
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="NewListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="Trace.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          name="NewListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>

 </configuration>
```

what this config do is log all exception occured **automatically** in a file and i dont need to code for that . im searching an easy way to log my exception to a svclog file untill client send it to me for debug **BUT** i want delete app.config and just use C# code for that.

Comment: Take a look at this article: [How to enable WCF traces programmatically?](http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/how-to-add-wcf-traces-programmatically/)

Comment: i dont want handle it programically i want do all in program and delete app.config

Comment: Doing it "all in program" **is doing it programmatically.**  If you don't want to use an app.config file then you will have to do it in the code - programmatically.  There is no third choice.

Comment: i read that site and what i understand is you create a custom class and in app.config he use that custom class ... so he still use app.config -- he want turn on or off tracing in this way he still have app.config but he can turn it off by code

Comment: Ah.  I didn't catch that part. There's a lot you can do either in code or via app.config - but this might something that is not achievable (at least not easily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i searched a lot so we cannot do that automatically but a good way for that :

```
public static class myClass
{

    [XmlRoot("Exception"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Exception")]
    public class exception
    {
        public exception()
        {
            ExceptionType = "";
            appDomain = "";
            Message = "";
            StackTrace = "";
            ExceptionString = "";
            InnerException = null;
            HelpLink = "";
            TargetSite = "";
            Source = "";
        }

        internal exception(Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionType = ex.GetType().ToString();
            appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
            Message = ex.Message;
            StackTrace = ex.StackTrace == null ? " - " : ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            HelpLink = ex.HelpLink == null ? " - " : ex.HelpLink.ToString();
            TargetSite = ex.TargetSite == null ? " - " : ex.TargetSite.ToString();
            Source = ex.Source == null ? " - " : ex.Source.ToString();
            ExceptionString = ex.ToString();
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                InnerException = new exception(ex.InnerException);
        }

        [XmlElement("ExceptionType")]
        public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("AppDomain")]
        public string appDomain { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("StackTrace")]
        public string StackTrace { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ExceptionString")]
        public string ExceptionString { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("HelpLink")]
        public string HelpLink { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TargetSite")]
        public string TargetSite { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Source")]
        public string Source { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("InnerException")]
        public exception InnerException { get; set; }
    }

    private static System.Diagnostics.TraceSource TraceLogger { get; set; }

    static myClass()
    {
        var xml = new System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ApplicationTrace.svclog");
        xml.TraceOutputOptions = System.Diagnostics.TraceOptions.Callstack | System.Diagnostics.TraceOptions.DateTime | System.Diagnostics.TraceOptions.LogicalOperationStack | System.Diagnostics.TraceOptions.ProcessId | System.Diagnostics.TraceOptions.ThreadId | System.Diagnostics.TraceOptions.Timestamp;

        TraceLogger = new System.Diagnostics.TraceSource("TraceLogger");
        TraceLogger.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.All;
        TraceLogger.Listeners.Add(xml);

        TraceLogger.Flush();
        TraceLogger.Close();

    }

    private static void WriteException(Exception ex)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            exception ee = new exception(ex);
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ee.GetType());
            x.Serialize(writer, ee);
            var xmlEncodedList = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            XmlTextReader myXml = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlEncodedList));

            XPathDocument xDoc = new XPathDocument(myXml);
            XPathNavigator myNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
            TraceLogger.TraceData(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, 0, myNav);
            TraceLogger.Flush();
        }
    }

    public static void HandleExceptions(Exception ex)
    {
       //do some thing then log
            WriteException(ex);
    }
}
```

each error occur in your application you can call this method or you can use application.DispatcherUnhandledException event for catch errors .

---

we create an exception class that can Serialize with xmlSerialization then we have a static trace source that log our exception.